# Disable button after clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two buttons on page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFLIGHT_INSERT" runat="server" Text="Inserisci Selezione" OnClick="btnFLIGHT_INSERT_Click" CssClass="btnFLIGHT_INSERT" Visible="False" CausesValidation="False" meta:resourcekey="btnFLIGHT_INSERTResource1" />

<asp:Button ID="btnFLIGHT_INSERT2"  runat="server" Text="Inserisci Selezione" OnClick="btnFLIGHT_INSERT_Click2" CausesValidation="False" meta:resourcekey="btnFLIGHT_INSERTResource1" />
```

I want `btnFLIGHT_INSERT` to be disabled after clicked, so nobody will be able to click on it twice.

I have tried to use `OnClientClick` - but then it executes only the client side function and doesn't call server side function:

```
protected void btnFLIGHT_INSERT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

I can't use `Page.IsPostBack` in pageLoad becasue I have one more button - `btnFLIGHT_INSERT2` which is OK if someone can press it twice.

So what can I do here?

Comment: if i do btnFLIGHT_INSERT.Enabled = false;
it will update only after the function will end. meanwhile i can press the button one more time... so its not good answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to page OnLoad:

```
btnFLIGHT_INSERT.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, null) + ";");
```

Taken from http://tgynther.blogspot.ie/2011/07/aspnet-prevent-button-double-click.html

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler `btnFLIGHT_INSERT_Click` you can disable your button by using `((Button)sender).Enabled = false;`.

Comment: if i do ((Button)sender).Enabled = false; it will update only after the function will end. meanwhile i can press the button one more time... so its not good answer..